# eAccelerator using FastCGI, control panel doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, joomla, fastcgi, eaccelerator

I've eaccelerator running on my server, with PHP under FastCGI. All works fine, but i can't access to eaccelerator control panel (it shows the user/pass dialog, but it doesn't accept any) if i configure PHP to run as an Apache module it works fine and i can access to eaccelerator control panel, but i need to use FastCGI due to permissions problems with files into the domain. How can i solve it? how can i use the control panel with FastCGI? does anyone have it working?
many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Open the file "control.php" in a text editor. Comment this portion like this:

```
/* {{{ auth 
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) || !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) ||
        $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != $user || $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != $pw) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="eAccelerator control panel"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    exit;
} 
 }}} */
```

Voila! No more password prompt

Comment: how to deactivate fastcgi in joomla?